# getActivity().findViewById(R.id.towrite) иногда возвращает null

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Пытаюсь получить и изменить `xml` элемент **Активити**, находясь внутри **Фрагмента**

1. Создаю переменную **в фрагменте**

   ```
   public TextView writeable;
   ```
2. В методе `OnActivityCreated` **(Тоже во фрагменте)** получаю в эту переменную xml-элемент. В этом методе **получается** написать текст в TextView

   ```
   @Override
   public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       writeable = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.towrite);
       writeable.setText("wtf?");
       super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
   }
   ```
3. Обрабатываю `OnClick`.

   На `xml`-кнопке написано `android:onClick="onButtonClick"`. Этот метод находится в **Активити**. Выглядит так:

   ```
   public void onButtonClick(View v) {
       KvaActivity myFragment = new KvaActivity();
       myFragment.onButtonClick(v); 
   }
   ```

   Вызываем метод `onButtonClick()`, который находится **во фрагменте**. Тут я пытаюсь написать текст в `TextView`, полученный в `OnActivityCreated`

   ```
   public void onButtonClick(View v) {
       writeable.setText("1234567");
   }
   ```

   Подходит только такой способ, у меня куча кнопок, для каждой не хочется прописывать `OnClickListener`, поэтому сделал с помощью xml. А нажатие на кнопку в коде видно только в активити.
4. Ну что ж, приложение вылетает после клика, смотрю логи:

   > Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Т.е. в `OnClick` переменная считается незаполненной. Как так, если в `OnActivityCreated` все прекрасно? И самое главное - как это исправить?

**UPD** Дополнил вопрос, почитав комментарии

Comment: "На xml-кнопке написано android:onClick="onButtonClick". Этот метод находится в Активити" - Этим все и сказано. В чем смысл вызывать onButtonClick() в активити и потом пытаться вызвать его во фрагменте? Переместите кнопку из активити во фрагмент и вызывайте ее только там

Comment: @АндроидАндроид Не получается. Нашел способ сделать только так. У меня куча кнопок, для каждой не хочется прописывать onClickListener. Если я пишу метод onButtonClick во fragment-е, то xml его не видит

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`KvaActivity myFragment = new KvaActivity();
myFragment.onButtonClick(v);`

Ошибка NPE возникает из-за того, что в `onClick` вы создаете **новый** объект фрагмента и вызываете метод у него.
Т.к. данный фрагмент был только создан, но *не был* добавлен с помощью `FragmentTransaction`, то и события жизненного цикла не вызываются.

P.S.

- findViewById(R.id.towrite) лучше вызывать в методе `onViewCreated` во фрагменте
- лучше все таки прописать обработчики у каждой кнопки во фрагменте

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)
Если кому-то будет нужно, то смог сделать с помощью тэга в `fragmentTransaction.replace()`

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, `getActivity()` возвращает `null`. Если так, то создайте переменную `View view`, в методе фрагмента `onCreateView` пишите

`view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.название_layout-файла_фрагмента, null);`,

далее вместо

`writeable = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.towrite);`

пишите

`writeable = view.findViewById(R.id.towrite);`

Comment: Нет, getActivity возвращает активити, проверил. В `onActivityCreated` все хорошо